# Comparing expressions of type object

Tags: c#, .net, types, typechecking

Okay, this is probably very simple but, I have the below "checks" `(not at the same time)` and the *First* **ALWAYS** evaluates to TRUE while the *Second* **SEEMS** to work.  This actually happens in each place that the row value is a number or bool`(Date seems fine...)`.

If I walk through the code in *Debug* it shows the value of `row["PersonID"]` as **162434**, the same as `tbxPersonID.EditValue`.  Is this just a basic and beginner truth about programming that I missed in my `hodge-podge-self-education`?

It seems, if I *cast* everything in question to a `string` first, I will be fine I would just like to know if I am correct and if there is a general rule as to what `Types` I would need to do this for?

### Doesn't Work

```
if (row["PersonID"] != tbxPersonID.EditValue)
{
    row["PersonID"] = tbxPersonID.EditValue;
}
if (row["CitizenFlag"] != chkCitizen.EditValue)
{
    row["CitizenFlag"] = chkCitizen.EditValue;
    _whatChanged.Add("CitizenFlag");
}
```

### Works

```
 if (row["PersonID"].ToString() != tbxPersonID.EditValue.ToString())
 {
     row["PersonID"] = tbxPersonID.EditValue;
 }

 if (row["CitizenFlag"].ToString() != chkCitizen.EditValue.ToString())
 {
     row["CitizenFlag"] = chkCitizen.EditValue;
     _whatChanged.Add("CitizenFlag");
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this just a case of comparing references?  Although if edit value is an int I don't understand this behavior.  In any case, have you tried .Equals()?

Comment: Can you make the title more general and searchable?

Comment: @dana: Thank you for the Edit
@orsandu63: Sure, any suggestions?  I didn't think people would be that interested in this....

Comment: @Henk:  Thank you!  If I had known to word the Title like that in the first place I doubt I would have needed to ask the question! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`row["PersonID"]` is of type object, which means that != and == will use *reference identity*. Basically you're comparing boxed values.

If you use:

```
if (!object.Equals(row["PersonID"], tbxPersonID.EditValue))
```

then you'll get *value equality* semantics, and I suspect you'll be okay - assuming that tbxPersonID really *is* an `int`, either boxed or not.

Just to make things concrete, here's a short but complete example to show what I'm talking about:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        object first = 2;
        object second = 2;

        // Compares reference equality: false
        Console.WriteLine(first == second);

        // Compares value equality: true
        Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(first, second));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jon, your example makes perfect sense!  I am still in awe that Dev's like you and others with so much experience are willing to stop and explain something so trivial to a beginner like me.

Comment: No trouble at all - and I wouldn't put too much faith in the idea that I have "so much experience." You should see sum of the dumb mistakes I make every day!

Comment: Thanks, As kind of a follow up, if it isn't beyond the scope of `comments`; is it a better idea to use `object.Equals()` vs `.ToString()`?

Comment: @Jon, like misspelling "some"? :)

Comment: @Jage: Aargh. That's dreadful. Sincere apologies. @Refracted Paladin: It's not a good idea to create textual representations unless that's fundamentally what you want to compare. It depends though - do you want (object)123L to equal (object)123? (i.e. comparing a boxed long with a boxed int.) I'd argue that usually if you get to that stage, you've probably got other problems.

Answer (score 2):

Whats the type of EditValue or the right hand value? The problem is probably that EditValue is not of type string (maybe its a subclass or something) therefore when you are doing != or == on it its doing a memory address compare instead of the compare for a string therefore you are getting false instead of true

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about C#, but in some languages the test of equality is different for numeric values and strings. So here you have to force a string comparison before it works.

Does this tell us something?

Answer (score 1):

Without the call to `ToString()`, your code is testing equality on two Objects rather then two numbers, thus the reason why it's not working.

By using `ToString()` your explicitly telling the code the get the values from the `row[]` and EditValue objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the data type of row[] object is something like int (or bool) and the chkCitizen.EditValue is of a different data type.  So you may be comparing '1' == 1 and having the result be false.

Answer (score 0):

"12345" != 12345